# Numbers and hebrew text cause unwanted new lines

Tags: android, textview, hebrew

For some unknown reason, if I put the following string:

```
15 קמ
```

in a text view, it results in a new line between the "15" and the "קמ":

```
15
קמ
```

If I replace the "קמ" with "km" then it works fine...

Note: this doesn't happen if both string's parts are Hebrew.

Any clues?

Comment: No new line on Galaxy Nexus, show some code.

Comment: What API level are you using when you see this? Is it on a real device or an emulator?

Comment: I use API 10, but I managed to reproduce the problem also in API 15. It happens both on a real device (HTC One X) & on the emulator...

Answer (score 3):

I think that hebrew is interpreted RTL (right to left) while the other part is LTR (left to right). Given this, the TextView has to represent something like this:

```
\LTR 15 \RTL קמ
```

My logical guess is that the TextView puts the RTL part on a new line to deal with the nonsense of having both parts on the same line. If you force it all the way RTL when the locale is hebrew, I think it would regulate the rendering and solve the issue. I would suggest you try adding the "RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK" character `\u200F` at the beginning of the string:

```
String text="15 קמ";
if (hebrew) {
    text="\u200F"+text;
}
```

Also, it seems that some fonts are showing a graphical interpretation of the special character (while it shouldn't). You will probably need to use this [font](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=SILHebrUnic2) to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

I have also experienced TextView alignment issue when I'm working with alphanumeric + arabic text in same text view, they will realign all the texts in left to right order which results ridiculous output. This kind of language issue is not really something we can fix in direct approach.

What we did were separating out the texts to more text views if applicable, which in your case I would suggest separating out the value and Hebrew text into separate TextView.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too...I really hoped there is a real solution and not just a workaround...Though it'll do the work...

Comment: @MukeshY Are you referring to shaylh? If you're I think you should leave the comment at his question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UTF-8 encoding for hebrew text, for eg:

> String text = "15 קמ";
>   text = new String(text.getBytes(), "UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

If your textview can fit in one line, I think I might have a solution. This is the xml layout that did the trick.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:text="15 קמ"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```